# Autoloading Symfony classes in Zend_Framework

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection, symfony1, autoload, zend-autoloader

How to autoload Symfony classes in the app based on Zend Framework? Can I push some kind of Symfony autoloader to the Zend's Autoloader?

I need to use some of the components like output escaper or dependency injection classes.

Comment: This look like what you are searching for : http://losohome.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/integrating-symfony-dependency-injection-service-container-with-zend-framework/

Comment: @greg0ire Not exactly. I'm looking for autoloader for all Symfony classes, not dependency injection solution.

Comment: I don't think thats possible. The sf autoloader depends on many sf project specific things like the cached autoloading-php files. You can take a look at the autoloader documentation (http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfSimpleAutoload) but I don't think it will help you any further

Comment: Check this link: http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/using-zend-framework-with-symfony

Comment: @ArneRie Thanks, but I'm looking for exactly the opposite approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend's autoloader can accept multiple autoloaders:

```
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array('ezcBase', 'autoload'), 'ezc');
```

The above is [straight from the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) and shows how to include the autoloader of ezComponents (now Zeta Components) as an additional loader. You can try to go this route by providing Sfs Autoloader.